# how to access videos from ipad inbuilt videos app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, video, ios7

I am working on an app in which I want to import videos from iPad's Videos.

Is that possible to access **video** app on iOS device?

**Note** I am not talking about photo library Or camera roll.

Comment: You cannot take from the actual "Videos" application that is on the iPad. You would only be able to get from photo library at the most.

Answer (score 1):

By this code you are able to get photo library videos of your device but not the inbuilt videos app.

**Objective C**

```
-(BOOL)startMediaBrowserFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller usingDelegate:(id )delegate {
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil)) {
        return NO;
    }
    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mediaUI.delegate = delegate;
    [mediaUI setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]];
    [controller presentViewController:mediaUI animated:YES completion:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
func startMediaBrowser(from controller: UIViewController?, usingDelegate delegate: Any?) -> Bool {
    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum) == false) || (delegate == nil) || (controller == nil) {
        return false
    }
    let mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
    mediaUI.delegate = delegate as? (UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate)
    mediaUI.mediaTypes = ["kUTTypeImage"]
    controller?.present(mediaUI, animated: true)
    return true
}
```